# Excel Average - Counting the number of variables

Tags: excel, count, average

I'm using the average function excel to get the average of a series of hotel prices in various European cities.

```
=average(21,42,63,84,105)
```

I'd like to be able to count the number of variables in each average function (for example, in the above example there's 5). The data is scrubbed from websites which is why it's in the format above rather than placed into separate cells.

Is there a way to do this without taking out the variables, putting them into a cell and then separating out the cells using Text to Columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fan of using UDFs, so here's an alternate method.

You can create a custom User Defined Function (UDF) for this. Just split the function by the deliminator and get your number from the `UBOUND()`.

```vb
Public function getNumArgs(inputRng as range) as long

    'First check that you are actually looking at a formula
    If Left(inputRng.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
        getNumArgs = False
        exit function
    End If

    getnumargs = ubound(split(inputrng.formula, ",")) + 1

end function
```

You will add 1 because VBA uses Base 0.

> You will then use your custom UDF the same way you do any other worksheet formula:
>
> ```
> =getNumArgs(A1)
> ```

*The largest benefit of using a UDF is that you do not have to remember a complex formula.*

Answer (score 4):

You can turn your equation into a string using `FORMULATEXT()` and then deduce the number of values being averaged by counting the instances of commas in your string (which relates to your final answer by `Total Commas + 1 = Total Values`

---

The first portion of the equation counts the character length **with** commas. The second portion counts the character length **without** commas. The difference is simply the number of commas present. We then add one since your last value is not followed by a comma

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),",",""))+1
```

*Assumes your average formula is in cell `A1`*

Comment: Can't see a better method of using worksheet functions. Well done!